# npm run serve failed

Tags: node.js, npm

When I try to run "npm run serve" in my terminal on my Mac. I get following error message. It works fine for a couple a hours ago, but not now. can anyone help me?

```
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/MYNAME/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/MYNAME/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/MYNAME/.npm/_logs/2020-09-03T12_46_01_362Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Is your current directory a Node project directory? Have you initialized the project with `npm init`?

Comment: The problem occurred because I was in the wrong folder

Answer (score 1):

***First check on your filesystem if the file EXISTS.***

for a new project, you always need to create a package.json, running

```
npm init
```

will create a package.json for you in the current directory.

if you want to instantly create a package.jsn using defaults, run

npm init -y

for more understanding refer this [npm guide](https://dzone.com/articles/an-absolute-beginners-guide-to-using-npm-1)

Answer (score 0):

If you say that everything worked before, then you are running this script in the wrong folder and npm cannot find package.json.

> no such file or directory, open '/Users/MYNAME/package.json'

Use the correct folder.